# Form field default value not working

Tags: 8, forms

I have an inherited project to which I need to add small form api changes. The changes are to two form fields shown below:

```
$form['start'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => t('Between:'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 1988,
    '#min' => 1900,
    '#max' => date('Y'),
    '#value' => 1988,
];
$form['test'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => t('TEST:'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 1988,
    '#max' => date('Y'),
    '#min' => 1900,
    '#value' => 1995,
];
$form['end'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => t('and'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#min' => 1900,
    '#max' => date('Y'),
    '#default_value' => 1999,
    '#value' => 1999,
];
```

This is a bizarre problem as my attempts to set the **#value** and **#default_value** for both the *start* and *end* fields are not working.

However, I created the **test** field and it successfully adds to the form and sets my configured value and default_value.

So, for the start field, I expect to see **1988** as the displayed value but instead that form field displays 1900.
The **test** field I create meanwhile displays and behaves properly ... go figure.

As it is an inherited project, **I wonder if there are other means of configuring a form which I am unaware of ?**

UPDATE: 
Thanks to Leymannx for contributing and attempting to help. As per your suggestions, I tried the following but **without success**:

```
$form['start'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => t('Between:'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#min' => 1900,
    '#max' => idate('Y'),
    '#default_value' => 1988,
];
```

**Note:** The problem is that both the start and end fields refuse all my efforts to configure the value and default_value. So, for the start field, I expect to see 1988 but instead that form field displays 1900.

Comment: I'd say `date('Y')` is the problem. Try [`idate('Y')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php) to format a local date/time as integer.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx but I think you misunderstand. The problem is that both the start and end fields refuse all my efforts to configure the value and default_value. So, for the start field, I expect to see 1988 but instead that form field displays 1900

Comment: Ah now I see. Remove `'#value'`.

Comment: @leymannx: Just tried commenting out '#value' but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: You should also try idate(). And remove #value. Then update your question if that's still not working

Comment: If you are setting #min to 1900, the form element is not showing any value that is lower than 1900, such as 1988. Why would you expect the form element not to respect the restrictions you are setting?

Comment: @kiamlaluno 1988 > 1900 ;)

Comment: @Clive I mean that setting #min, the form element will show that value as starting value, if it doesn't get a default value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed all `'#value'` keys and replaced `date('Y')` with [`idate('Y')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php) and for me it's working without any problem. **Flush cache!**

```
$form['start'] = [
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#title' => t('Between') . ':',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => 1988,
  '#min' => 1900,
  '#max' => idate('Y'),
];
$form['test'] = [
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#title' => t('TEST') . ':',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => 1988,
  '#max' => idate('Y'),
  '#min' => 1900,
];
$form['end'] = [
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#title' => t('and'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#min' => 1900,
  '#max' => idate('Y'),
  '#default_value' => 1999,
];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've been flushing caches each time I saved the code. It has to be something else.

Comment: @sisko – Must be something unique to your form or project. Try to paste the code to some other form. Just for testing. Maybe there's another form field with the same key in your form?

Comment: Or there could be a form alter, a theme function/preprocessing for these fields that's messing with the default value

Comment: Or JavaScript...

Comment: It seems a contradiction, setting the minimum value to 1900, and then setting the default value to 1988. If those properties are used, I would expect they are respected from the form elements.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – 1988 isn't lower than 1900 or what do you mean?

Comment: The form element is showing the #min value if an initial value is not set. That is the OP's issue, which we cannot reproduce.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – I tried it out. It just shows nothing, when no #default_value is set. No matter what #min and #max where set.

Comment: There must be code that is interfering in some way, from the same module, or a different one. If I recall correctly, Drupal also uses validation on client side, but I don't know in which way a browser or JavaScript code could interfere with that.